# Using Leaflet inside Bootstrap container?

Tags: leaflet, bootstrapping

I have problem rendering leaflet map in a webpage using bootstrap.  I have two columns col-4, col-8 in a bootstrap container. the col-4 has some text and col-8 has to render the leaflet map. But the map overlaps all other containers. I am not getting the styling right. Below is the html, css and js code.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
                <title>Bootstrap Version</title>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <meta name"viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


                <script type="text/javascript" src="js/uikit.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="js/leaflet.js"></script>


            </head>
            <body>




            <nav class ="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role ="navigation">
                        <a class="navbar-brand"  href="#"><img id ="logo" src="image/bootstrap.png">Bootstrap</a>   


                <div class ="container-fluid">
                    <div class ="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" class ="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-main">
                                <span class="sr-only">Navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>



                    </div>

                    <div class ="collapse navbar-collapse" id ="navbar-collapse-main">
                        <ul class ="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

                        </ul>

                    </div>      

                </div>
            </nav>



            <div class="padding" id ="map-container">
            <div class="container">
                    <div class ="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, qui ea delenit qualisque, ne duo tollit dolore hendrerit. Exerci postulant eos at, has causae electram id. Legimus contentiones eum te, eos eligendi vituperata ad, no ferri offendit referrentur vis. Homero virtute habemus ad sed, nec ferri viris in. Te labore adolescens ius, his consulatu eloquentiam ea, mea nulla appareat dignissim an. Ei his magna expetenda, nihil copiosae quo ut, percipit insolens mea an.
                            </p>


                        </div>

                        <div class ="col-md-8">

                            <!--p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, qui ea delenit qualisque, ne duo tollit dolore hendrerit. Exerci postulant eos at, has causae electram id. Legimus contentiones eum te, eos eligendi vituperata ad, no ferri offendit referrentur vis. Homero virtute habemus ad sed, nec ferri viris in. Te labore adolescens ius, his consulatu eloquentiam ea, mea nulla appareat dignissim an. Ei his magna expetenda, nihil copiosae quo ut, percipit insolens mea an.
                            </p-->
                            <div id="map"></div>

                        </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>          
            </body>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
            </html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body{
                        height:100%;
                        width:100%;
                    }

                    .navbar{
                        background-color:#FFFFFF;
                        padding:1% 0;
                        font-size:12px;

                    }

                    .navbar-brand{
                        min-height:60px;
                        padding:0 20px 5px;
                        font-size: 16px

                    }

                    #logo{
                        height:55px;
                        width:55px;
                        margin: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
                        display:inline-block;
                    }


                    .navbar-default .navbar-nav li a {
                        color:#707b7c;
                    }

                    #navbar-collapse-main{
                        margin-right: 30px
                    }

                    #map-container{

                        padding-top:120px;
                        padding-left:10px;

                    }


                    #map {
                    position: absolute;
                    margin:0;
                    padding:0; 
                    border: 1px solid black;
                    border-radius: 8px;
                    }
```

JS:

```
console.log("Document ready!");

        // initialize the map on the "map" div with a given center and zoom
        var map = L.map('map', {
            center: [50.99, 10.191],
            zoom: 6,
            minZoom:6,
            maxBounds:[[55.3915921070334,20.610351562500004],[47.17477833929906,1.7138671875000002]]
        });



        var basemap = L.tileLayer("https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png");
        basemap.addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your map is missing a width and height. It's also specified as `position:absolute`, which will get it outside the flow of its container (the `.col-md-8`).

The critical bit of HTML is:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4" style='border: 1px solid red'>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8" style='border: 1px solid red '>
      <div id="map"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And the critical bit of CSS is:

```
#map {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 400px;  /* or as desired */
  width: 100%;  /* This means "100% of the width of its container", the .col-md-8 */
}
```

See an [adapted example at this plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/wnzPgjKW8AiNzkQBlcgB?p=preview).

(This is besides your example code missing the Leaflet CSS, [as noted by TomazicM](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/315757/53755))

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `leaflet.css` style link. Since you are using local Leaflet, I suppose it should be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/leaflet.css">
```

You have also to specify map width and height. Width can be 100%, height has to be specific value in this case.

```
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  margin:0;
  padding:0; 
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

Comment: yes I comment out the link to leafelt.css because with it i do not see the map at all

Comment: You cannot do without `leaflet.css`. I discovered one other thing. You have to declare height and width of map div. Width can be 100%, height has to be specific value in this case. I modified my answer.

Comment: Only now I discovered that IvanSanchez already discovered and answered this. I probably saw it at about the same time, but I'm watching Tirreno-Adriatico cycling on may PC at the same time and so was late in publishing the answer :-).